# Removing words from text with separators in front(using Regex or List)

Tags: c#

I need to remove words from the text with separators next to them. The problem is that the program only removes 1 separator after the word but there are many of them. Any suggestions how to remove other separators?
Also, I need to make sure that the word is not connected with other letters. For example (If the word is fHouse or Housef it should not be removed)

At the moment I have:

```
public static void Process(string fin, string fout)
{
    using (var foutv = File.CreateText(fout)) //fout - OutPut.txt
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fin)) // fin - InPut.txt
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] WordsToRemove = { "Home", "House", "Room" };
                char[] seperators = {';', ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':'};
                foreach(string word in WordsToRemove)
                {
                    foreach (char seperator in seperators)
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(word + seperator, string.Empty);
                    }
                }
                foutv.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have :

```
fhgkHouse!House!Dog;;;!!Inside!C!Room!Home!House!Room;;;;;;;;;;!Table!London!Computer!Room;..;
```

Results I get:

```
  fhgkDog;;;!!Inside!C!;;;;;;;;;!Table!London!Computer!..;
```

The results should be:

```
fhgkHouse!Dog;;;!!Inside!C!Table!London!Computer!
```

Comment: You can probably do that with regex but not without effort. I suggest you tokenize the text and loop through the collection of tokens you've identified to remove the unnecessary ones. It's a bit complicated to set up but I'm sure it'll work. Read: https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2016/2/3/creating-a-simple-tokenizer-lexer-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex : `\b(Home|House|Room)(!|;)*\b|;+\.\.;+`

See at:  https://regex101.com/r/LUsyM8/1

In there, I substitute words and special characters with blank or empty string.

It produces the same expected result I guess.

Comment: I can't use words in regex, is it possible to insert  list or array in regex?

Comment: Yes, it is. The pattern is just a string so you can concatenate string pieces using `string.join(array,separator)` to join all the words in the middle of the expression. However make sure you don't have special chars in the joined words otherwise the pattern will not be valid. To avoid that, use `Regex.Escape()` method.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/EKfXysZ10fz4 there are still some problems

Comment: I fixed it. Try this : `string[] words = new string[3]{   Regex.Escape("House"),   Regex.Escape("Home"),   Regex.Escape("Room") }; string pattern = @"\b(" + string.Join(words,"|") + @")(!|;)*\b|;+\.\.;+";`

Comment: string.Join(words, "|") doesn't work. but string.Join("|", words) works

Comment: Sure, my bad! I inverted the parameters. Sorry.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/9RIV7b4q3_jI but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Nevermind, it does work, I forgot to change the output :D

Comment: I will check later if this works with the whole code

Comment: Tried this on the whole code and there's still some errors https://prnt.sc/VdP9LN2kOQUw it leaves some words without deleting them and also doesn't delete all of the separators

Comment: Of course, I expected that. The regex I gave as solution is based on the example of text you wrote in your post and on the result you'd expect. So, in order for us to give the appropriate answer, can you update the post with the whole input text you're trying to process, please ?

Comment: My bad, next time I will try to put the whole Test.txt. I fixed the rest, but once again thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help! Regex is cool and powerful when it works. You can avoid writing tons of lines of code to process some text. However you can spend hours to find the correct regular expression. By the way, for your own knowledge, Regex is behind the processing of all server tags in an ASPX web page, and all T4 templates. They're everywhere!